# Verify how command was executed

Tags: linux, security, wordpress, php5

I run few PHP webpages with NGINX and PHP-FPM.
Recently I hosted site for friend who had security issues with WordPress, did all upgrades, WP and Plugins.

But somehow I found out today that user under which his site is run in PHP-FPM is running system commands e.g. `/usr/bin/host`
I did not found any overwritten files, and running commands is disabled in `php.ini` for `php-fpm`.

1. Is there any way to find how commands are run, are they run directly by PHP process, or there is some script on server that is executed?
2. Can I limit commands to which user have access?
3. Good books/articles on Linux server security where I can search for more info?

Server is running up to date Ubuntu LTS 14.04, with Ubuntu version of NGINX and PHP.

Comment: You might get more answer in "information security", try there.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I limit commands to which user have access?

Yes, you can, by expanding the `disable_functions` parameter in your php.ini file (location depends on your setup, e.g. `/etc/php5/cgi/php/ini`)

```
disable_functions = system,exec,shell_exec,escapeshellcmd,show_source,leak,ini_restore,pfsockopen,popen,eproc_c,posix_kill,posix_setuid,posix_setpgid,posix_setsid,proc_open,proc_terminate,proc_get_status,proc_nice,proc_close,passthru,pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority
```

Comment: Yes, that is true for PHP script and I use that option. But I also had situation where atacker uploaded Perl script in upload bug in PHP script and than executed it (don't know how exactcly). And in situation like that I would like to prevent that user from using commands like ping, or curl etc.

Comment: Lol, ok so the question you posted is broader than I understood first. You are not only concerned about PHP command but also about shell commands. You can configure `/bin/false` as shell for www-data in `/etc/passwd` or use suPHP, so the programs run as other users so you have more possibilities to restrict their access.

Comment: @sebix, most probably if someone has reached the point of executing shell commands from the web he hasn't logged in, thus the shell the user has in /etc/passwd is not executed and has no effect at this stage, although it is a good security measure if that user never has to be logged in to the system.

Comment: Ok, I did what @sebix suggested and now I'm waiting for next atacker to test this on next attack.

Comment: @YoMismo Yes there's much more involved in hardening a server, this question is very broad.